# Algorithm sub-numbering but not based on sections using algorithmicx

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithmicx

I'm writing a paper where I try to update an algorithm to improve its performance. I want the original algorithm to be numbered "Algorithm 2" and the improvements should then be "Algorithm 2.1", "Algorithm 2.2" etc. Is this possible using algorithmicx? The algorithms are not all in the same section.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\section{Tail move reversal algorithm} 
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \label{alg:reversal}
    \caption{Tail move reversal}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \State $x = 0$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\section{Tail move rearrangement algorithm}  %this is the original algorithm 
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \label{alg:rearrangement}
    \caption{Tail move rearrangement}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \State $y = 1$
    \State $x = 1$
    \State apply Algorithm \ref{alg:reversal} to $x$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\section{First improvement}  %I'd like this one to be numbered 2.1
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \caption{First improvement Algorithm \ref{alg:rearrangement}}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \State $y = 2$
    \State $x = 3$
    \State apply Algorithm \ref{alg:reversal} to $x$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}



\section{Second improvement} %I'd like this one to be numbered 2.2
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \caption{Second improvement Algorithm \ref{alg:rearrangement}}
    \State $y = 2$
    \State $x = 3$
    \State apply Algorithm \ref{alg:reversal} to $x$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would you please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing how you use the algorithm-related packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a new command `\setAlgoImprovement{<label of algo being improved>}` is provided. It need a second run. See the use example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{refcount} % for \getrefnumber

\makeatletter
% #1 = the label of original algorithm
% must be used before \caption
\newcommand{\setAlgoImprovement}[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \ifnum\@tempa=0\relax
    % label #1 is not defined, first run
  \else
    \ifcsname c@algo\@tempa:imp\endcsname
    \else
      % define new counter "algo<n>:imp" for improvement of algorithm <n>
      \newcounter{algo\@tempa:imp}%
    \fi
    \stepcounter{algo\@tempa:imp}%
    \edef\x{%
      \noexpand\renewcommand\noexpand\thealgorithm{\noexpand\getrefnumber{#1}.\noexpand\arabic{algo\@tempa:imp}}%
    }\x  
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Tail move reversal algorithm} 
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \label{alg:reversal}
    \caption{Tail move reversal}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \State $x = 0$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\section{Tail move rearrangement algorithm}  %this is the original algorithm 
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \label{alg:rearrangement}
    \caption{Tail move rearrangement}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \State $y = 1$
    \State $x = 1$
    \State apply Algorithm \ref{alg:reversal} to $x$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\section{First improvement}  %I'd like this one to be numbered 2.1
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \setAlgoImprovement{alg:rearrangement}
    \caption{First improvement Algorithm \ref{alg:rearrangement}}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] 
    \State $y = 2$
    \State $x = 3$
    \State apply Algorithm \ref{alg:reversal} to $x$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}



\section{Second improvement} %I'd like this one to be numbered 2.2
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \setAlgoImprovement{alg:rearrangement}
    \caption{Second improvement Algorithm \ref{alg:rearrangement}}
    \State $y = 2$
    \State $x = 3$
    \State apply Algorithm \ref{alg:reversal} to $x$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

and output

[image]

Comment: This is not what I seek. I want to sub-number in a specific way, not based on the sections the algorithms are in.

Comment: @Violet Reread your question, I now understand your requirement. Sorry for misunderstanding before.

Comment: @Violet Hi, I've updated my answer. Hope this time I didn't misunderstand again.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much.